# Is there any way to reference names within pubspec.yaml?

Tags: flutter, dart, yaml, pubspec

Is there any way to reference a predefined name in pubspec.yaml?

I am trying to reference the "name" key's value in a structure used by a plugin

```
name: tpoly
description: A new Flutter application.

# [...]

flutter_launcher_name:
  name: *name
```

At the end the plugin should receive (basically the value should get substituted),

```
flutter_launcher_name:
  name: tpoly
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First declare the variable using `&`. Here, `foo`, for example:

```
name: &foo tpoly
```

To refer, use `*`.

```
flutter_launcher_name:
  name: *foo
```

Comment: I am doing fine too. You're about to reach 100k. Congratulations! Where is the party tonight?

Comment: Tell me the location and I'll catch a flight, book a cab and reach asap ;)

Comment: Ok, then you're invited to Berlin, Germany :)

Comment: Hmm...Are you Manuel Braun?